# Another jQuery version in function closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing some script, which developers will include on their pages.
I need jQuery in this script. And if page already have jQuery, don't override them. I want to use my jQuery(in my anonymous function). And i want to page use jQuery whitch used before me(not my jQuery).
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: First of all is your code backward compatible? I mean is it gonna work on jquery 1.3?

Comment: Yes.But i want use only my version of jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Here’s an example:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>window.$jq164 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>window.$jq171 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Now you can use `$jq164` and `$jq171` separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm thought that if i don't call noConflict on first script it doesn't work, but jquery remembers old object.